# Does $S$ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does $S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n (e- (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n)$  converge or diverge?

My attempt  : I know that  $e = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}( 1+ \frac{1}{n})^n$.

Now put the value  e in   given series $S$ , I got $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n (e- (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n (e- e)=0$

so the given series  is converges

is  it  correct????

Comment: Personally I would be looking to use the alternating series test for this. You should work out the first few terms to get a sense of what is happening - though the general term tends to zero, each term is itself constant and doesn't vary with $n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series converges, but not for the reason you state.

It is known that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ converges to $e$ monotonically. Therefore $e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ is a sequence monotonically decreasing to $0$ and  Leibniz criterion applies.